# Sort array by particular element type first and next based on sort order

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have array for example

```
const array1 = ['x123', 'y123', 'z123', 'a123', 'b123', 'a123' , 'z123']
```

Is there way to move particular elements for example 'z123' first to the array and sort rest of the element based on the alphaNumeric order using array1.sort() or some other function.

The final array should be

```
array1 = ['z123', 'z123', 'a123', 'a123', 'b123', 'x123', 'y123']
```

Comment: Write a comparison function that always considers `z123` to be lower than anything else.

Comment: An easier way would be to extract all the `z123` elements from the original array, sort the array without them, and then concatenate those two into the result.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript - sorting array by multiple criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28560801/javascript-sorting-array-by-multiple-criteria)

Answer (score 2):

You could compare and take the delta or sort by string.

```js
const array = ['x123', 'y123', 'z123', 'a123', 'b123', 'a123', 'z123'];

array.sort((a, b) => (b === 'z123') - (a === 'z123') || a.localeCompare(b));

console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a very simple - although not a very efficient - way of doing it (the regular expressions will potentially be applied very often in the course of the sorting process):

```js
 const array1 = ['x123', 'y123', 'z123', 'a123', 'b123', 'a123' , 'z123'];
 
 console.log(array1.sort((a,b)=>a.replace(/^z/,"0").localeCompare(b.replace(/^z/,'0'))));
```

This snippet will sort anything starting with 'z' to the front of the array.

**Update:**

Being "woken up" by the upvote I looked at the post again and considered making the script a little bit more "robust" and applicable for very large arrays. Taking @Barmar's idea of first separating the "z"-candidates from the rest of the list I came up with the following case-insensitive sorting:

```js
const arr=['x123', 'Z112', 'y123', 'z123', '0011', 'A123', 'b123', 'a023', 'z023'],      
      res=arr.reduce((a,c)=>(a[0+(c[0].toLowerCase()!="z")].push(c),a),[[],[]])
             .flatMap(ar=>ar.sort((a,b)=>a.toLowerCase().localeCompare(b.toLowerCase())));
             
console.log(JSON.stringify(arr));
console.log(JSON.stringify(res));
```

The expression `a[0+(c[0].toLowerCase()!="z")].push(c)` will push the current element `c` into one of the two arrays `a[0]` or `a[1]`, depending on the comparison `c[0].toLowerCase()!="z"` which is converted into a number by adding `0` to it. Both arrays are then sorted separately and combined into a "flat" output array by means of the `.flatMap()` call. The sorting function itself is based on `localeCompare()` in combination with `.toLowerCase()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can get items you want to be on the top and then sort the rest of the array. At the end concat them together as below:

```js
const array1 = ['x123', 'y123', 'z123', 'a123', 'b123', 'a123' , 'z123'];
const itemOnTop = 'z123';
const itemsOnTop = array1.filter(item => item === itemOnTop);
const sortedItems = array1.filter(item => item !== itemOnTop).sort();
console.log([...itemsOnTop, ...sortedItems]);
```