# order roman-numbers in javascript

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I have a function in javascript where the `schoolClass` it's an roman number like this `I`, `II`, `IV` etc. this function is called multiple times and the result it's concatenated in an array like this:

```js
const generateClasses = (schoolClass, number) => {
  const classes = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < number; i++) {
    classes.push(`${schoolClass}-${(i + 10).toString(36).toUpperCase()}`);
  }
  return classes;
};
let output = [];
output = output.concat(generateClasses('II', 2));
output = output.concat(generateClasses('I', 1));
output = output.concat(generateClasses('IV', 2));
console.log(output);
```

in the end the output it's like this:

```
["II-A", "II-B", "I-A", "IV-A", "IV-B"]
```

how to order the array-like `["I-A", "II-A", "II-B", "IV-A", "IV-V"]`
I appreciate any help!
PS: for converting numbers in roman I use the `roman-numbers` module

Comment: Use sort, split the string on -, convert the roman numeral into a number (plenty of scripts out there), compare it

Comment: can you show me an example? for converting numbers in roman I use the `roman-numbers` module

Comment: @CosminCiolacu, please first try, and if it doesn't work, show your code (that attempts to order the data) in the question and indicate where you are stuck with it.

Comment: What is the greatest Roman number you will ever get in your input?

Comment: @trincot for school grades, I expect XII. Although I'm not sure if all countries have 12 school grades.

Comment: @VLAZ in my country the schools has 12 grades :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert the Roman numeral to a normal (Arabic) one to compare. Since you have very constrained amount of Roman numerals, the easiest way is to just hardcode them - no need to involve an algorithm that transforms them if you only have 12 different possible inputs.

With hardcoded values for **I** to **XII**, you can [sort based on multiple criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28560801) by splitting your string on `-` and:

- sort by the part before the dash [as a number](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1063007).
- the part after the dash [as a string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1129216).

```js
const romanTable = {
  "I"   : 1,
  "II"  : 2,
  "III" : 3,
  "IV"  : 4,
  "V"   : 5,
  "VI"  : 6,
  "VII" : 7,
  "VIII": 8,
  "IX"  : 9,
  "X"   : 10,
  "XI"  : 11,
  "XII" : 12,
};

const arr = ["II-A", "II-B", "I-A", "IV-A", "IV-B"];

arr.sort((a, b) => {
  const [mainA, secondaryA] = a.split("-");
  const [mainB, secondaryB] = b.split("-");
  
  if (mainA !== mainB)
    return romanTable[mainA] - romanTable[mainB];
   
  return secondaryA.localeCompare(secondaryB);
});

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 2):

As school grades are limited to 12, the alphabetical sort isn't that bad to start with. For the example you have given you could just call `.sort()` on that array and it would be fine.

Actually, only "IX" would get sorted at the wrong place. So let's deal with that:

```js
let classes = ["XII-A", "IX-A", "VII-A", "II-A", "II-B", "I-A", "IV-A", "IV-B"];
let trans = s => s.replace("IX", "VIIJ");
classes.sort((a, b) => trans(a).localeCompare(trans(b)));
console.log(classes);
```

This would work for Roman numbers that don't use any other symbols than I, V and X, so up to 39.

Comment: Quite clever. I'd probably change `s.replace("IX", "VIIII")` - it's kind of technically correct. At least more intuitive than adding a J.

Comment: Looking at your nick, I should probably have chosen "VIIZ" ;-)

Comment: :D makes it sounds like a number invented during the ancient Roman zombie apocalypse.

Answer (score 0):

Here I converted the Roman to Integer by iterating each Roman character So XII will be (10+1+1)

Now Sort them but if 2 Roman character are same than I compare the Alphabet attached with it.

```js
const num = ["II-B", "II-A", "I-A", "IV-A", "IV-B"];

num.sort((a, b) => {
  const diff = roman_to_Int(a.split("-")[0]) - roman_to_Int(b.split('-')[0]);
  if (diff === 0) {
    return a.split("-")[1].localeCompare(b.split("-")[1]);
  }
  return diff;

});

console.log(num);

/* Source - https://www.w3resource.com/javascript-exercises/javascript-math-exercise-22.php */

function roman_to_Int(str1) {
  if(str1 == null) return -1;
  var num = char_to_int(str1.charAt(0));
  var pre, curr;
  for(var i = 1; i < str1.length; i++){
    curr = char_to_int(str1.charAt(i));
    pre = char_to_int(str1.charAt(i-1));
    if(curr <= pre){
      num += curr;
    } else {
      num = num - pre*2 + curr;
    }
  }
  return num;
}

function char_to_int(c){
    switch (c){
      case 'I': return 1;
      case 'V': return 5;
      case 'X': return 10;
      case 'L': return 50;
      case 'C': return 100;
      case 'D': return 500;
      case 'M': return 1000;
      default: return -1;
    }
}
```