# Sorting javascript object by number (value), then abc order by string (key)

Tags: javascript, sorting, object

I'm having trouble sorting through this array in a way that's in the title where words are the keys and value is the count.

```js
const words = {
  "be": 3,
  "a": 5,
  "an": 3
}
```

Desired out put would be:

```js
{ 
"a": 5,
"an": 3, 
"be": 3
}
```

```js
Object.entries(wordCount).sort(([, a], [, b]) => b - a)
```

But I don't know how I would sort items with the same value in abc order :'(

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sorting object property by values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069666/sorting-object-property-by-values)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript - sorting array by multiple criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28560801/javascript-sorting-array-by-multiple-criteria)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sort array of objects by string property value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129216/sort-array-of-objects-by-string-property-value)

Answer (score -1):

Using [the clever technique](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50580263/38522) found in another answer:

```js
const words = {
  "be": 3,
  "a": 5,
  "an": 3
}

const sortedEntries = (o) => 
    Object.entries(words)
          .sort(([k1, v1], [k2, v2]) => 
              v2 - v1 || k1.localeCompare(k2))

console.log(sortedEntries(words))
```