# Sorting time zone by GMT- then Neutral after with GMT+

Tags: javascript, sorting

I need to sort a time zone.

I would like to sort by `-` then `nutral` (no - or + ) then `+`. at present it sorts at `-`, `+` and `nutral`.

Sorting code:

```js
 const SortTimezoneCompare = (data) => {
    return data.sort((a, b) => {
        var re = /^\(GMT([+-]\d{1,2}):(\d{1,2})\).*$/;
        var aOffset = parseFloat(a.label.replace(re, '$1.$2'));
        var bOffset = parseFloat(b.label.replace(re, '$1.$2'));
        return aOffset < bOffset ? -1 : aOffset > bOffset ? 1 : 0; 
    });
};

const array = [
    
    {
        "defaultOrder": 34,
        "label": "(GMT-01:00) Cape Verde Islands",
        "codeId": 1218,
        "code": "CVT",
        "codeDesc": "(GMT-01:00) Cape Verde Islands",
        "codeQualifier": "Time_Zone_Cd"
    },
    {
        "defaultOrder": 41,
        "label": "(GMT+01:00) Amsterdam, Berlin, Bern, Rome, Stockholm, Vienna",
        "codeId": 297,
        "code": "CET",
        "codeDesc": "(GMT+01:00) Amsterdam, Berlin, Bern, Rome, Stockholm, Vienna",
        "codeQualifier": "Time_Zone_Cd"
    },
    {
        "defaultOrder": 40,
        "label": "(GMT) Monrovia, Reykjavik",
        "codeId": 1220,
        "code": "GMT02",
        "codeDesc": "(GMT) Monrovia, Reykjavik",
        "codeQualifier": "Time_Zone_Cd"
    }
];

const r = SortTimezoneCompare(array);

console.log(r);
```

[Live Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/XONgWl7sNh9ekxxN?open=lib%2Fscript.js)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your code is, you are not considering the case where you don't have `+` or `-` right after `GMT`, which results in `NaN`.

```js
const SortTimezoneCompare = (data) => {
    return data.sort((a, b) => {
        var re = /^\(GMT([+-]\d{1,2}):(\d{1,2})\).*$/g;
        var matches = {
          a: [...a.label.matchAll(re)],
          b: [...b.label.matchAll(re)]
        };
        var aOffset = 0;
        var bOffset = 0;parseFloat(b.label.replace(re, '$1.$2'));
        if (matches.a.length > 0) // matched with - or +
          aOffset = parseFloat(`${matches.a[0][1]}.${matches.a[0][2]}`);
        if (matches.b.length > 0) // matched with - or +
          bOffset = parseFloat(`${matches.b[0][1]}.${matches.b[0][2]}`);
        //console.log(aOffset + "--" + bOffset);
        return aOffset < bOffset ? -1 : aOffset > bOffset ? 1 : 0; 
    });
};

const array = [
    
    {
        "defaultOrder": 34,
        "label": "(GMT-01:00) Cape Verde Islands",
        "codeId": 1218,
        "code": "CVT",
        "codeDesc": "(GMT-01:00) Cape Verde Islands",
        "codeQualifier": "Time_Zone_Cd"
    },
    {
        "defaultOrder": 41,
        "label": "(GMT+01:00) Amsterdam, Berlin, Bern, Rome, Stockholm, Vienna",
        "codeId": 297,
        "code": "CET",
        "codeDesc": "(GMT+01:00) Amsterdam, Berlin, Bern, Rome, Stockholm, Vienna",
        "codeQualifier": "Time_Zone_Cd"
    },
    {
        "defaultOrder": 40,
        "label": "(GMT) Monrovia, Reykjavik",
        "codeId": 1220,
        "code": "GMT02",
        "codeDesc": "(GMT) Monrovia, Reykjavik",
        "codeQualifier": "Time_Zone_Cd"
    }
];

const r = SortTimezoneCompare(array);

console.log(r);
```

Comment: You saved my day. But not able to understand how it's works. will spend time to understand using your comment. thanks!!